# Is "enough" enough or should I say "that's enough"?

Tags: expressions

My children are arguing loudly and to make them stop I yell:

Enough!

Is that natural? Or should it be:

That's enough!

Answer (score 1):

You say `That's enough` to tell someone, especially a child, to stop behaving in a silly, noisy, or unpleasant way.

Whereas,
`Enough` gives more angry vibes because it, as we know, means **something in an adequate amount**. Therefore, saying only a single word (and that also in another reference) **Enough** is a bit rude.